# H$^1 (G,\mathbb{Z}) \cong$ Der$(G, \mathbb{Z})$/PDer $(G, \mathbb{Z})\cong$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \neq {0}$.

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

$G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite cyclic group.

Then H$^1 (G,\mathbb{Z}) \cong$ Der$(G, \mathbb{Z})$/PDer $(G, \mathbb{Z})\cong$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \neq {0}$.

Is there something wrong with the last isomorphism. Should it be
H$^0 (G,\mathbb{Z})\cong$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$?

This is from P592 of Rotman's Homological algebra book. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How does $G$ act on $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: hello Angina, were you asking or giving a hint?

Comment: Here I suppose we view $\mathbb{Z}$ as a trival $G$-module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general $H^1(G,A)$ is the group of crossed homomorphisms $G\to A$
factored out by the principal crossed homomorphisms.

If $G$ acts trivially on $A$ then crossed homomorphisms are just homomorphisms
and the principal crossed homomorphisms are all zero, so $H^1(G,A)=\text{Hom}(G,A)$.

Comment: But we still have H$^0 (G,A)\cong$ Hom$(\mathbb{Z}, A)$, right? So H$^1$ $\cong$ H$^0$ in this case?